# Any way to get database data back?

Tags: mysql

So I've entered a couple hundred rows of data into a database manually and have begun implementing a Java frontend. However, I got an unexpected result and now when I go back into RazorSQL, the database is gone (I believe a DROP command was executed). Is all the data I entered gone forever?

Part of this I believe stems from me not fully understanding where databases are stored. I'm using RazorSQL on OS X and can't seem to find a path where the database is stored.

Answer (score 2):

[Undrop tool for InnoDB](https://launchpad.net/undrop-for-innodb) can scan you disk and retrieve records that are not overwritten yet.
I didn't test it on OSX though, only Linux-es are supported.

Comment: I don't think this tool will work though because the database itself was removed, not just the table. Thanks though!

Comment: Since 2008 I recovered thousands cases like yours. Believe me, I know what I'm taking about. Check this for example  https://twindb.com/recover-after-drop-table-innodb_file_per_table-on/